# Flutter deeplinking working in android simulator with sdk-version 30 but not with androidSDK > 33

Tags: flutter, deep-linking

I have implemented deeplinking for android as in the flutter docs
(https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links)

with

```
        <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myApp.my-server.de"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

in the android manifest.
(myApp.my-server.de is a placeholder and not the real server name in my code)

Calling
.\adb shell 'am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "https://myApp.my-server.de/my-deeplink/1"' and the opened device is with sdk 30 it
opens the choice to open the app or the website on the virtual device and everything is working. Having a device with sdk 33 just opens the browser.

What could be the problem? The play store tells me the deeplink-url is valid (GooglePlayConsole > Deeplinks > "All links work. Users go directly to your app" [translated from de]).